# How to save selected item from dropdownlist in asp.net mvc2

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

simply I have an Employee class and Department class and the employee must be in a department, when I save the Employee I want to save the selected department also.
any one have a code sample or any solution.

Comment: which ORM are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Nicholas for ur support I found a solution to get the selected value from dropdownlist in the controller.
u can make it like that

```
 string EmplyeeId = Request["EmplyeeId "];
```

u will get the id of the selected item

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NHibernate you may wish to Fluent NHibernate as your Mapper.

There is a getting [started](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Your_first_project) tutorial on the Fluent NHibernate wiki which will give you a great overview of the coding required to provide a solution to your coding problem.